# EF - Access derived types from context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Here's an example of my issue. Here are my EF classes...

```
public class basetype{
}

public class derived : basetype{
}
```

Is there any way to directly access derived entities from the database context in the following manner?

```
context.derived.Where(c=> c. whatever...);
```

As it stands when using the context I can only see

```
context.basetype
```

Comment: Have you tried 'OfType'(e.g. `context.baseTypeEntities.OfType<derived>().Where(..)`)?

Comment: Yes but what I'm more concerned about is if I'm relating back to another entity that's a different type that is derived from the same base class it's a pain to handle. Such as...

    context.basetype.TypeOf<derived>().First().NavigationPropertyBackToBaseClass.SomePropertyOfThatDerivedType

Because that navigation property only goes back to the base class and I need to directly access a derived type with the Id in the navigation property